# How can i install PIL, if this happens?

Tags: python

```
sudo pip install PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/x/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: which OS are you using ?? and python version ?

Comment: PIL is not available for python3. Use pillow instead, it is a fork of PIL that is still being developed

Comment: I use OSX and i have python 2.7

Comment: Did you the try the `--allow-external` flag as it suggests?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of PIL use pillow. pillow is fork of PIL.

for installation instruction in Mac OS X use the below link,

https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation